# Get div content from a child div onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a wrapper div1, with div2 inside which contains a string. When i click on div1 i want the content from div2 to appear in alert(); how can this be done ?

```
document.getElementById(feats).addEventListener("click",function show() {
            var htmlstring = this.innerHTML;

            alert(htmlstring);
```

The code above simply just add an even listener and alert all the html code from the wrapper.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which is well worth learning:

```
$('#div1').click(function() {
    alert($('#div2').text());
});
```

Comment: I haven't dv'd you, but I disagree. Loading a heavy library for such a simple job is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Richard - I agree. But there are usually more jobs.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="div1" onclick="doAlert();" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">
<div id="div2">
  Hello, this is the contents of div2
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function doAlert() {
    alert(document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML);
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, gentle nudge, you will get more responses if you start accepting answers.